# passing data in components in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, components

I am new in react native and facing a issue in passing data to the component.

having a component named WebSocket ,In this have multiple parameters to be accepted like below

```
  const WebSocket = ({
   socketUrl,
   socketFirstRequest,
   socketSecondRequest,
}) => {
// connecting socket and sending data to socket.
}
```

Now How to use this components at multiple places to send data to this component
I tried this but not working like this.

```
const InstrumentList = () => {
  // my request params for GC1_URL,socketFirstRequest,socketSecondRequest
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {checkStatus === false && (
        <WebSocketGC1
          socketUrl={GC1_URL}
          socketFirstRequest={socketFirstRequest}
          socketSecondRequest={socketSecondRequest}
        />
      )}
 </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to react component for this functionality. React component useful if you render something on the UI side. From your implementation, I think you create a custom react hook. For example https://github.com/robtaussig/react-use-websocket or https://rossbulat.medium.com/react-hooks-managing-web-sockets-with-useeffect-and-usestate-2dfc30eeceec

Comment: I have given one condition for this if checkstatus === false ,then only it will send data,I don't think it will create any issue in rendering  the UI.@Kirill Novikov

Comment: you can pass this as a hook param